# MakeMKV libbdplus - How to play 2013 / 2014 BD+ Discs?

Tags: blu-ray

I have a Bluray of Star Trek Into Darkness (2013). Is there any way to play this legally bought bluray on my ubuntu computer? I found something here:

http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7009

can i use this method to play this disc with vlc media player?

I am not sure, because this thread is very old....

I searched the internet for a long time, but it looks that people just had this problem in 2008 or 2009 because i cant find any newer website or forum thread which doesnt says that this method works only for older blurays with older BD+ protection.

So, second question, is it somehow possible to play this bluray on my computer?

If u need additional information, feel free to ask me!

THANKYOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not *that* old. Mike uses his forum as a place to document features like that.

I have been using MakeMKV for a couple of years to great effect. I haven't tried direct playing (and I can't find a Bluray disk to test right now) but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Okay, so ill try it out! :) Can i use the shared object files also after my freeware license of makemkv has expired?

Comment: It's sort of a rolling freeware so just download the new version and run through the make scripts again. It's a pain but it works. You shouldn't need to recreate the links.